# Best pattern to read a configuration object

Tags: java, design-patterns

I need to map a configuration file into an object `Configuration` (this is already done) which is a composition of several configuration objects, each one used by a service. For instance, the `Configuration` class is composed by `ConfA` and `ConfB` classes:

```
public class Configuration {

    private ConfA confA;
    private ConfB confB;

    //getters and setters
}
```

Then we have an interface `Service` implemented by classes `ServiceA` and `ServiceB`, each one uses `ConfA` and `ConfB` respectively:

```
public interface Service {

    void work(Configuration configuration);
}
```

With my current approach, in each particular service I have to do something like this to obtain the proper configuration:

```
public class ServiceB implements Service {

    @Override
    public void work(Configuration configuration) {
        ConfB confB = configuration.getConfB();
    }
}
```

Is there any pattern to avoid this code repetition `ConfB confB = configuration.getConfB();` in each service? Any way to avoid the service to know how to retrieve their own configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reckon that you can do simpler:

```
public class ServiceB implements Service {

    @Override
    public void work(ConfB bConf) {
        ConfB confB = bConf;
    }
}
```

So high level module will inject `ConfB` into lower level module `ServiceB`.

Comment: I think your answer is incomplete. The code you posted does not compile because the overrided method is incorrect. I believe you meant to use generics like ServiceB implements Service<ConfB>, Service class declared as Service<T extends Configuration> and method work defined as work(T configuration) in the parent class. Please, let me know your thoughts about my comment.

Comment: @Juan yeah, you can use Generic or what is more suitable for your. It depends on your code. If both configurations ConfA and ConfB have the same behaviors, then you can extract abstraction and use it as a parameter at your constructor. E.g. `public void work(IConf conf)`